# Cannot Login after Fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, login

I just installed 14.04.1 on a desktop computer. Everything installed just as usual, but my user account does not show up when the new system starts. All I have is a guest session!

When I try to login to my account from a command prompt using CNTRL-ALT-F2, my username and password are accepted but the screen just flashes a brief message and returns immediately to the login prompt. The message is far too quick to see.

The guest session works fine, but I have no administration privileges on my machine!

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert yet.

The fastest way to solve the problem is to logging in as `root` user. The second alternative is by creating a new account and activating the `sudo` mechanism.

Please take a look further in:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

Comment: Since I can only login as a guest, I do not have access to the sudo command. It is VERY frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a bootable disk, (eg the installation media), you could try using that to add a user to the local system. Not sure if it's different on Ubuntu but if you add a new user to the system by editing one into the */etc/passwd*, */etc/shadow*, and */etc/group* files you may be able to log in. If it's a new install you may not be able to log in as root since root has no password on a fresh Ubuntu installation. I suppose you could use the boot disk to give root a password too ;).

Alternatively, you could try and view */var/log/syslog* and see if there are any messages there after trying and failing to log in.

Answer (score 0):

If a fresh install is in a trouble the best way to fix it - just to reinstall. And BE SURE to NOT CHECK "Do not require password at login" while creating a base user.

Comment: I have re-installed several times, always with the same result. I have not checked the (Do not require password at login" option.

Comment: More than strange indeed... Did you try to hit a triangle next to "Guest session" on the login screen - you username should be present in the drop-down list... I understand it's ridiculous but it may happen sometime